# Object reference is required for non-static field, method, or property

Tags: c#, winforms

I have the below code in my form:

```
    public static void setRichText(string TextIn)
    { 
        rtxStatus.AppendText(TextIn);
    }
```

I have a richtextbox print control, and I want to append text to it in different formats (some bold, some regular text).

This is so I can append text to the control in the form then print it.

In my class I have this code to append text to the control, and after the entire text file has been formatted and appended I will print the contents of the rich text control.

```
    frmCashierPrinting.setRichText(pqRequests[s]);
```

(`pqRequests` is an array or list populated by using Split on a string)

But I am getting a compile error:

> An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'BCPrintQ.frmCashierPrinting.rtxStatus'

what am I doing wrong please?

Comment: take static out of the setRichText method name or make pqRequests Static

Comment: thanks but pqRequests is a list, so I am looping through it, and hoping to add some lines in Bold...

Comment: so what if it's a list... Make  static to get rid of this error

Comment: @AMR the problem is with `rtxStatus` not `pqRequests`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code fails because `setRichText` is defined as a static method, even though you call it using an object reference.

Remove the `static` keyword from the method declaration, ie:

```
public void setRichText(string TextIn)
{ 
    rtxStatus.AppendText(TextIn);
}
```

You would also need to ensure all callers of `setRichText` to call the method using a reference to an existing Form instead of accessing it as a static method.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried this but when I call the method on the form from my external class using `frmCashierPrinting.setRichText(pqRequests[s]);` I get an error **An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'BCPrintQ.frmCashierPrinting.setRichText(string)'**

Comment: This would happen only if frmCashierPrinting is the class name of the form. Replace it with a proper reference to your form's instance. Forms do NOT have some default instance that you can access using static methods. VB.NET uses some compiler magic to create an instance and return it as if it were a default, but C# doesn't do this. Where are you creating an instance of your form and how is it called?

Comment: ok I fixed that, but when I try to call the method 'setRichText' from my external class **BCPrintQSpooler** it is not found